Debian no sound over HDMI
Sound wont play over HDMI,I tried all options from this list but no luck. Also my lap top has only 1 HDMI port, not sure what all these options come from.


HDMI is a cabling standard. Any of those devices could be at the other end. Pick one that matches your particular other end. I also wonder about the "Profile: Analog Stereo Ouput" in the top right. It's a dropdown list. Have you looked?

I tried every single combination nothing worked
